# Fetching Array of Data from Backend with Angular 9

Tags: angular

I need a little bit help with Angular (9). I do a GET Request to fetch a list of Users from the Backend:

```
    getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this._constant.baseAppUrl}/users/all`, )
        .pipe(map(user => {

            return user;
        }));
    }
```

My Goal is to get an Array of Objects with a type of the User Model. Instead I get an object.

[image]

I don't understand why. My IDE also shows, that the user variable is User[], but in the browser the typeof user is "object".

So how can I get an array back?

EDIT: This is the Answer from the Backend:

```
{
   "5ea04cfbcd595b393d78acbb": {
      "isAdmin": true,
      "role": "User",
      "status": "cEmail",
      "_id": "5ea04cfbcd595b393d78acbb",
      "name": "Test",
      "password": "$2b$10$re0gqblgXsfYus1mYA3yQ.Oiz4x81c3M2uxfE4tG6V7tNW1JMubXi",
      "email": "dr@rootix.de",
      "__v": 0
   },
   "5ea1f308fc8909618668384e": {
      "isAdmin": true,
      "role": "User",
      "status": "cEmail",
      "_id": "5ea1f308fc8909618668384e",
      "name": "Mathias Braun",
      "password": "$2b$10$zpQezfiG4xNkwOTgV4CLIeYU4MITVfL2VhlLC3rqCbjBGl5TIpavG",
      "email": "mb@rootix.de",
      "__v": 0
   }
}
```

Comment: Have your API actually return an array..?

Comment: Are u subscribing your result from return of GetUsers() method?

Comment: this.http.get<User[]> <--This is saying get an array.  But obviously, the back end is not returning an array. Right?

Comment: Thank you for your Comments, I updated my previous posting with the answer of the API

Comment: Data you are getting from backend is object not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend is not returning the Array according to your provided JSON. But you can convert the object into the Array on the Angular side using the following way.

Modify your Api call function

```
getUsers():Observable<User[]> {
   return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this._constant.baseAppUrl}/users/all`, )
    .pipe(map(response=> {
       if(response){
          return Object.values(response); //This will return the array of object values.
        }
        return []; // If response is null return empty array for safety.
    }));
}
```

Now your getUsers() function will array of user object.